# Why does Nedry have a photo of Oppenheimer on his computer monitor?

Tags: jurassic-park

In Jurassic Park, computer programmer Dennis Nedry has a picture of the famous physicist (and "father of the atomic bomb") J. Robert Oppenheimer taped to his computer monitor.  Above the photo is a piece of paper, with a doodle of a mushroom cloud.<sup>1</sup>

[image]

### Why?  What is this supposed to mean?

---

---

<sup>1</sup> Note: Later, after Nedry has sabotaged park security and absconded with the dinosaur embryos, we see another note above the Oppenheimer photo;  this one reads "Beginning of the Baby Boom".  This note makes some sense, since Nedry is going to be selling potential dino-babies;  however, it doesn't explain why he has a photo of Oppenheimer.

[image]

Comment: There should be a hand-drawn circle on your first picture.

Comment: Nedry has a pipe fetish.

Comment: This Oppenheimer quote sums up Nedry and his theft plot: *"There are no secrets about the world of nature. There are secrets about the thoughts and intentions of men."*

Answer (score 25):

Upon completion and testing of the first bomb, Oppenheimer famously recalled the text from the Bhagavad Gita - "I am become death. The destroyer of worlds". Possibly a subtle shout out to the fact that Nedry, in this situation, was indeed the bringer of death.

> We knew the world would not be the same. A few people laughed, a few
>   people cried, most people were silent. I remembered the line from the
>   Hindu scripture, the Bhagavad-Gita. Vishnu is trying to persuade the
>   Prince that he should do his duty and to impress him takes on his
>   multi-armed form and says, "Now, I am become Death, the destroyer of
>   worlds." I suppose we all thought that one way or another.

*http://www.atomicarchive.com/Movies/Movie8.shtml*

Video of Oppenheimer and the above text:

Further drawing a parallel between Oppenheimer's work on the bomb and the themes of Jurassic Park is his quote:

> When you see something that is technically sweet, you go ahead and do
>   it and you argue about what to do about it only after you have had
>   your technical success.

*http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/americanexperience/features/transcript/oppenheimer-transcript/*

and how that parallels Ian Malcolm's line:

> Yeah, but your scientists were so preoccupied with whether or not they could that they didn’t stop to think if they should.

Credit to [this site](http://nickpage.co.uk/stuff/oppenheimer-and-jurassic-park/) for explicitly calling out that parallel in terms of the two quotes:

Comment: Actually, that quote (and the video in which it appears) is the primary reason I recognized him in the photo.  I'm not quite convinced by your answer, but it is interesting.  +1